# Installing gcc 10 on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: compiling, gcc

Is there any better way of installing gcc and g++ 10 on Eoan Ermine than building it from scratch?

`ubuntu-toolchain-r-test` seems to only target LTS releases.

Comment: Is it worth it, there are only a few weeks of life left in 19.10/eoan (9 months is 17th July..)

Comment: @guiverc - well I needed it yesterday, so yes. I will move to 20.04, but when I was installing Ubuntu 20.04 wasn't out and 18.04 didn't have enough hardware support for my new laptop.